# Documenting destructured function argument with rest parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdoc

Is it possible to correctly document something like this using JSDoc?

```js
/**
 * CartFooter component
 *
 * @type {React.FunctionComponent}
 *
 * @param {Object} footerProps          props
 * @param {Object} footerProps.classes  classes injected from the parent
 * @param {Object} footerProps.events   events for the component
 * @param {Object} footerProps.children events for the component
 * @param {Object} footerProps.props
 * @param {React.Ref<Object>} ref
 * @returns {JSX.Element}
 * @constructor
 */
const CartFooter = ({ classes: parentClasses, events, children, ...props }, ref) => { /* ... */ }
```

I don't understand how to document the rest param `...props` correctly in this case:

If I hover over `...props`, VSCode describes it as

```
(parameter) props: {
    props: any;
}
```

Which is incorrect, if I do

```
const { a, b, ...options } = props
const { c, d } = options
```

Inside the function body, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` have red lines, with the error `Property 'q' does not exist on type '{ props: any; }'.ts(2339)`

I don't understand why the type of `...props` is `{ props: any; }`. If I change

```
 * @param {Object} footerProps.props
```

to

```
 * @param {...any} footerProps.props
```

I get the error `A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list.ts(1014)`.

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks